# Using a filter/map to condense a for loop

Tags: python

Is there a way to write a `filter` or `map` do the the following as a one-liner?

```
formatted_data = []
for hit in res['hits']['hits'][:201]:
    src = hit['_source']
    formatted_data.append({
        'path': src['path'],
        'size': src['size'],
        'last_modified': dateutil.parser.parse(src['last_modified']).date()
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a oneliner using map and lamda function that i came up . But its less readable

```
formatted_data=map(lambda x : {'path':x['_source']['path'],'size': x["_source"]['size'],'last_modified': dateutil.parser.parse(x["_source"]['last_modified']).date() },res['hits']['hits'][:201])
```

I think if you really want to use map write another function and make it more readable like

```
def returndict(x):
        return {
                'path':x['_source']['path'],
                'size': x['_source']['size'],
                'last_modified': dateutil.parser.parse(x['_source']['last_modified']).date() 
        }
print(map(returndict,res['hits']['hits'][:201])])
```

I would like to quote [zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

> Beautiful is better than ugly. Explicit is better than implicit.
>
> Simple is better than complex. Complex is better than complicated.
>
> Flat is better than nested. Sparse is better than dense.
>
> Readability counts.

Answer (score 2):

It's going to be quite ugly:

```
formatted_data = [ {
        'path': hit['_source']['path'],
        'size': hit['_source']['size'],
        'last_modified': dateutil.parser.parse(hit['_source']['last_modified']).date()
} for hit in res['hits']['hits'][:201] ]
```

but you may stretch it into a single line if you like.

Comment: It is ugly, but it's a one-liner. I think this is a trap that's easy to fall into with Python. You're given the tools and ability to compress what many other languages would have in verbose loops into a one-liner. It's alluring to think that you can shorten something, and so you chip away at it until it's as small as possible. But in reality I find in my own code that, a week later, those compressed lines are the biggest headaches to re-understand and debug.